# How to document static class properties in PHP

Tags: php, yii, phpstorm, phpdoc

Given the following scenario, where you have a static property on `Foo` documented as an instance of `FooApp`, an extended class `Bar`, and at runtime it turns out that the static property is actually set to an instance of `BarApp` rather than `FooApp`:

```php
class Foo
{
    /** 
     * @var FooApp
     */
    public static $app;
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
}

Bar::$app = BarApp();
```

…what is the proper way to document `Bar` so that it’s clear that its static `$app` is going to be set to a `BarApp` instance rather than `FooApp`?

I’ve tried the following but PhpStorm doesn’t respect it, probably because `@property` isn’t meant for static properties:

```php
/**
 * @property BarApp $app
 */
class Bar extends Foo
{
}
```

So far the only thing I’ve come up with is actually overriding `$bar` in the code:

```php
class Bar
{
    /** 
     * @var BarApp
     */
    public static $app;
}
```

This is a bit annoying since it results in extra code when theoretically extra documentation would have sufficed (as in the case of overriding instance-level properties and methods’ documentation using `@property` and `@method`).

(The use case here is a Yii application - `Foo` represents `BaseYii` and `Bar` represents a custom class that extends it; `FooApp` represents `yii\base\Application` and `BarApp` represents a custom class that extends it.)

Comment: I think you actually want extra code here, the problem is if you don't then it's actually possible for you to pass a FooApp into your Bar, and the way your code is writing the expectation is that would work, and that's what your documentation is currently saying.  

Property is explicitly supposed to be used with the _get and _set magic methods, and if you don't have those, then there's nothing for @property to set, though I havent used property much so I might be off base here

Comment: I understand that it's not actually being enforced; that's fine. I just want the docs to reflect what will actually be the case at runtime, so things like PhpStorm's autocompletion work correctly.

Comment: I think you're going to have to explicitly call this out unfortunately.  You could refactor some other code that solves this, if you did something like add a singleton pattern where you can explicitly call out the different product in Bar::GetApp() or whatever.  Otherwise I just dont think logically there's any typehinting that makes sense here short of what you've got in your last and annoying example

Comment: *"I’ve tried the following but PhpStorm doesn’t respect it, probably because @property isn’t meant for static properties:"* You should have tried proper syntax then: `@property static BarApp $app` (although I still not sure that it will work -- AFAIK proper/real property declaration still takes over, at least in current PhpStorm versions)

Comment: @LazyOne funnily enough I've just found this question four years later, and this still does not work, neither does your suggestion - PHPStorm simply complains about _Undefined class static_ for that syntax. Seems like it's simply not possible.

Comment: @MoFriedrich That's because there is still no `@property` syntax for static fields, only for `@method`. Maybe you can use (create one) static method that will return get that field and use it that way in your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Please note: This is a tracking answer to help people arriving here from search results.**

At the time of writing, there simply is no (official) documentation tag to annotate *"magic"* static properties, neither in the [PHPDocumentor standard](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html) nor the [proposed PSR19](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc-tags.md).

If you're part of the PHP-FIG (looking at you @Chuck Burgess), you might want to consider adding this to PSR19, preferably as an extension of the `@property` tag — for example like so:

```
 * @property static type $name Free text description
```

With *"static"* being an optional keyword that may be omitted for non-static, virtual properties.

Otherwise, I've opened [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-47833) on the PHPStorm issue tracker. If you'd like this being implemented in PHPStorm, consider voting for it.